# Restore database in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I deleted my app on Firebase, then after a week I want to restore it, is that possible? I understand that there is a note that it will be permanently deleted after confirming.. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Firebase keeps backups of the data in your Realtime Database. If you accidentally delete data from your database, you can [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) and ask for the data to be restored.

You can also check out [Announcing Automated Daily Backups for the Firebase Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/announcing-automated-daily-backups-for-the-firebase-database.html)

Comment: The update to this from Google is: "In order to more efficiently process your issue, we now only accept new support requests through our support portal at https://firebase.google.com/support/ "

Comment: Firebase support is great. They restored my database in couple of hours. It's not exactly restore but creating another copy. Very helpful

Comment: You get mail regarding your project shutdown, in which they provide a restore link. so simply open that link and select the project you want to restore and click restore.

Answer (score 4):

If you delete your project, dont worry. You have 30 days for recovery in Google Cloud Platform. Then you will receive a email with a link for this.

`https://console.developers.google.com/cloud-resource-manager?pendingDeletion=true&organizationId=` some ID

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry but the answer is no.
the rollback is available only with firebase hosting.

for the future you should download a backup by simply clicking on 'Export Data' in your project root.

Comment: Do keep in mind that "Export Data" is an operation that gets more expensive as your database grows. Combine that with the fact that it pulls the data over the same infrastructure as the users of your app, make this approach less ideal. We typically recommend either continuous/streaming backups or using [Private Backups](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-03-05-private-backups-for-firebase-data.html).