# Recover accidentally deleted data from firebase (not whole project or database)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Someone accidentally deleted a key which had loads of data from firebase realtime db via the cloud console.

No backup is available, so is there a way I can recover that?

PS: Note that Its not a whole project or a database that's been deleted, but just a key from firebase that had lots of data!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959363/2305594

Answer (score 5):

If you are a blaze plan user, you have the option to set up automated backups for your database.

However, seeing that you are asking this question I doubt that you have those available: AFAIK, there is no way of restoring deleted data apart from restoring a backup since the related data has been removed from the database.

There are great concepts and options for database backups as well as database auditing / versioning out there, I recommend looking into that to prevent further incidents.

**EDIT**
As Joseph pointed out in the question comments, you can contact firebase support to help you as they keep backups of your data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959363/2305594

**EDIT 2**
As you pointed out, you did specify 'not the whole database'. However, you could download the backup and extract the specific data yourself, manually adding it back to the database. The backups are stored on a google cloud storage bucket in an easily readable JSON format.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But that happens to be the first(or atleast one of the first) in google search result for firebase accidental data deletion. That's why I explicitly mentioned "not whole project or database" as that answer is in response to a question about deleted FULL database.

Comment: And yeah I enabled the backups. So thanks for suggesting :)

Comment: I just contacted their support and they could help.

Comment: Please can you post how support was able to help.  I have this same question and would like to know how it was handled.  Thanks.