# I can recover original data after modifying it with ".update" in Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the [Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5db6wfvH8gIVFQaICR372QKuEAAYASAAEgI1yvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) database with `JavaScript` and `Node.js`.

I accidentally modified a document inside collection that contained very important data.

I did this using the `.update` method as explained in the [Update a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_8) section of the official Firebase documentation.

The point is that since I was using test data, when modifying the document I did not update its data correctly, but rather I overwritten the original information with the test data.

Since I didn't do any kind of backup of that data, my question is ...

**Is there a way to get back the original data that I overwritten using the `'.update'`?**

Comment: Unless you have backups set up, probably not. You could wait for the official Firebase team to see this but in the meantime I highly recommend you set up and use the emulators to avoid having this situation again

Comment: Since you mention the "official Firebase team"... it would be useful to contact them through the [Contact Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) as they suggest in this answer [Restore database in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954986/restore-database-in-firebase/35959363#35959363)?

Comment: Sure you can do that as well, you can also link this question in the report

Answer (score 3):

Firestore does not automatically keep back ups of your data, so unless you set up an automatic [export of the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) yourself the previous contents of the document are lost.

If this is business critical data, you could try [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. But since you said it's test data, the better path is likely to figure out how to set up your test data automatically in a way that makes it reproducible in case of a coding mistake like this one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Was production data but fortunately it wasn't many, so maybe it's no necessary to retrieve them. I will consider your recommendation about data export.