# Is there a way to revert or undo recent changes in Firebase Realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I made a mistake of using `set()` instead of `update` and it overwrote the entire collection.

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, no.  There is also no manual process you can control by default.  You would have to establish a backup process ahead of time, and restore from the backup.

See also:

- [Restore database in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954986/restore-database-in-firebase)

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately we don't have the backups turned on.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

As Doug said, there is no API to restore data that you overwrite or deleted.

If you accidentally overwrite data in the Realtime Database, **immediately** [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. They *may* be able to help restore the data from a backup.

Comment: If you don't have the database backup turned on, is it still makes sense to reach out to Firebase support?